# Tor proxy UDP sendto() function, python

Tags: python, proxy, udp, tor

I want send data using UDP through Tor proxy service, I try this way:

```
from socket import AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
import socket
import socks



socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9150)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
s = socket.socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
s.sendto(data, TARGET)
```

But I obtain these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py"  in <module> s.sendto(data, TARGET)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/socks.py", line 396, in sendto
self.bind(("", 0))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/socks.py", line 382, in bind
_, relay = self._SOCKS5_request(self._proxyconn, UDP_ASSOCIATE, dst)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/socks.py", line 552, in _SOCKS5_request
raise SOCKS5Error("{0:#04x}: {1}".format(status, error))
socks.SOCKS5Error: 0x07: Command not supported, or protocol error
```

Comment: https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/4524/10070

Comment: Very usefull thanks